# In Python, how do I execute a .exe file, and stop it after n seconds?

Tags: python

I am using "subprocess" to execute a .exe file from a Python script. I need to do this in a loop, ie start the .exe, run it for a minute, kill it, do it all over again.

I am using subprocess.check_call to execute it with arguments, but I don't know how to stop it.

Answer (score 0):

`subprocess.check_call` is used to check the returned value - use `subprocess.Popen` this returns a process ID, (`pid`), which can be used after your time limit with `pid.terminate()` to end the process, (kill it).